# How can I distinguish an OP's bounty from a third party in Data Explorer?

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer

I am quite new to creating queries in SEDE, but I am pretty sure one cannot distinguish bounties granted by an OP from third-party bounties. Am I right?

Could this be changed?

Answer (score 7):

Now that [user information is populated for bounty-related votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110182/add-userid-information-for-bounty-starters-and-closers), you can compare `Votes.UserId` against `Posts.OwnerUserId` to determine if a bounty was offered  by the OP, or someone else.

As an example, here are the [last ten bounties on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67068) (from the last time Data Explorer was updated), with an indication of whether or not they were self-offered.

Answer (score 4):

I've made the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1370218) that shows the count per type of bounty for users that offer bounties on their own questions.

The main query (a CTE reallt) called ownbounties joins the Votes (typeid=8), PostHistory (typeid=33), Posts, PostNotices and PostNoticeTypes tables to get the actual 'bounty" type (ClassId=2 in PostNoticeTypes).

The representation of that data is then handed off to a PIVOT query.

```
;with ownbounties as
(
select -- top 100 
       p.id 
     , p.owneruserid 
     , pnt.name
     , pnt.id [noteid]
     , v.creationdate [vcd]
     , pn.creationdate [pcd]
     , ph.creationdate [phcd]
from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
inner join postnotices pn on pn.postid = p.id
inner join postnoticetypes pnt on pn.postnoticetypeid = pnt.id
inner join posthistory ph 
      on   ph.postid = p.id 
       and ph.comment = pn.id -- comment has the FK for postnotice
where v.votetypeid = 8 
and v.userid = p.owneruserid -- bounty on own post
and pnt.classid = 2 -- bounties 
and ph.posthistorytypeid = 33 -- notice added
)

select owneruserid as [User Link]
     , [10] [outdated]
     , [11] [attention]
     , [12] [improve]
     , [13] [authorative] 
     , [14] [canonical]
     , [15] [reward]
     , [10]+[11]+[12]+[13]+[14]+[15] [total]
from (select owneruserid, id, noteid 
from ownbounties) as pvtdata
pivot 
(
  count(id) 
  for noteid in ([10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15])
) as pvt
order by [10]+[11]+[12]+[13]+[14]+[15] desc
```

When run today this is what it shows:

[image: query with bountie givers and 5 columns with counts]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Is this run on a single site, or network wide?

Comment: @Luuklag on one site. It might be a tad too heavy to run on all sites.