# Add UserId information for bounty starters and closers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, data-explorer, data-dump

Currently the "UserId" info is stripped from the `Votes` table for "BountyStart" and "BountyClose" vote types (i.e. for `VoteTypeId=8` and `VoteTypeId=9` respectively, [check an example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58821/check-the-presence-of-bountyamount-and-userid-data-for-bountyxx-vote-events)). Since this information is public on the SO (can be seen in [question rev. history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5256858/revisions) and in [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648313/idolon?tab=bounties) as well) it would be nice to have it also available in the Data Dump.

***@Those who upvoted this request:*** you may also like the related one [Add bounty details to Data Dump for "BountyStart" event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115855/add-bounty-details-to-data-dump-for-bountystart-event).

When both of these requests got implemented we'll be able to write sophisticated queries determining top bounty starters and winners, altruists and sponsors etc. (and yeah, we could propose some new badges to reward them). So if you like it, support it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, makes sense.

1. I added the bounty starters
2. I added the start amount for the bounty
3. You can extrapolate by the "end" amount of the bounty if it was awarded by community or not

Coming to the data dump near you ... some time in the next few weeks / days

I see no point in adding info for the closers ... you can figure that one out anyway.