# Add bounty details to Data Dump for "BountyStart" event

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, data-explorer, data-dump

There is a `BountyAmount` column in the Data Dump, but for now it is only filled for `VoteTypeId=9` ("BountyClose" event, i.e. when bounty ended) and only if the bounty was awarded to someone ([see an example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58821/check-the-presence-of-bountyamount-and-userid-data-for-bountyxx-vote-events)).

Can we also have `BountyAmount` column filled for the "BountyStart" event (`VoteTypeId=8`)  - with the original amount of the bounty when it was started for the question?

This information is [public on the SE](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5256858/revisions) itself, so I see no reason for it to be excluded from the Data Dump.

p.s.: if this request got implemented (along with [Add UserId information for bounty starters and closers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110182/158912)), it would be finally possible to create a query for bounty details retrieval from the Data Dump.

Comment: Does that info even exist anymore?

Comment: @Bobby - Sure. This information can be seen in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5256858/revisions) and in [user profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158912/idolon?tab=bounties&sort=offered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, makes sense.

1. I added the bounty starters
2. I added the start amount for the bounty
3. You can extrapolate by the "end" amount of the bounty if it was awarded by community or not

Coming to the data dump near you ... some time in the next few weeks / days